# How do I prevent water from leaking down my chimney?

Tags: water, chimney

When it rains hard, I get a decent amount of water coming in through my chimney. Is this normal?  What can I do to minimize this?

It's a relatively new house; it has a guard on top, and the chimney is in great shape.

Comment: OK, I can say it's not normal. Things we need to know: Is the chimney brick or is it wood-sided? Is the flue clay (orange pipe sticking out) or is it metal? Is the cap on the chimney masonry or metal? There's a LARGE number of places it could leak from. Best bet is to post a picture of the chimney ... taken from up on the roof if at all possible.

Comment: Brick chimney with a cap on top, which is metal I believe.  I think the flue is metal, honestly haven't looked at it yet.  Good idea, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chimney cap? If not, start there. If there is a chimney cap, and it's a brick chimney, odds are you have cracks and/or missing mortar--at which point I'd say your chimney is unsafe...both as a combustion exhaust (you don't want fumes leaking into the house) and as a safety issue (falling bricks hurt). I'd call out a licensed chimney inspector/cleaner/sweep.